# Spring-boot-mail MailSendException, could not connect to host

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gmail, jakarta-mail

I want to try javaMailSender in my application. But i can not connect to smtp server, when i try to send a message, i receive this error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
```

Here are properties from application.properties

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.mail.password = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
```

And MailSender:

```
@Service
public class MailHelper {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

@Autowired 
private MailContentBuilder builder;

public void sendMail(String destination, String body){
    try {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setSubject("Price Tracer : Notify");
        helper.setTo(destination);
        String[] args = body.split(",");
        helper.setText(builder.build(args[0],args[1],args[2]),true);

        javaMailSender.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("Printer");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: First, [get rid of all those socketFactory properties, you don't need them](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  Most likely you have a firewall that's preventing you from connecting directly.

Comment: That was the issue with firewall, this code is working on 2nd computer flawlessly . thanks.